# How to add a field with the sum python function in a Qweb Report?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I am trying to inherit Qweb Report. I am successful in inserting static values inside my qweb Report but when I try to add some computed module it doesn't show me the values.

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="delivery_order_report" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">
            <xpath expr="//table[@id='mytable']" position="inside">
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sum</td>
                        <td><t t-esc="sum([o.pack_operation_ids.pack_lot_ids.qty for o in docs])" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

You can see my code my inheriting qweb report of model named as `stock.report_picking`. When I have tried to fetch `o.origin` it showed me the field successfully . Below is the code:

```xml
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="delivery_order_report" inherit_id="stock.report_picking">
            <xpath expr="//table[@id='mytable']" position="inside">
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td>sum</td>
                        <td><t t-esc="o.origin" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong python expression. Try this:

```xml
<t t-set="result" t-value="0" />
<t foreach="o.pack_operation_ids" t-as="pack" >
    <t t-set="result" t-value="result + sum([x for x in pack.pack_lot_ids.mapped('qty')])" />
</t>
<t t-esc="result" />
```

Comment: Sorry but i solved it in simpler way . I am going to post it here Please add your reviews